# How to make np.ma.argmin return None if every element is masked?

Tags: python, numpy, argmax, masked-array

Motivation: in a list of numeric values I try to find the index of the smallest value - with the side condition, that the value has to below a certain treshold. Here is an example where everything works as expected

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 5, -4])
threshold = 3
b = np.ma.MaskedArray(a, a >= threshold)
np.ma.argmin(b)  # returns 2, since a[2] is -4 which is the smallest element < 3
```

Here is a case where `np.ma.argmin` does something unexpected:

```
a = np.array([4, 5])
threshold = 3
b = np.ma.MaskedArray(a, a >= threshold)
np.ma.argmin(b)  # returns 0, expected a None etc. since there is no element < 3
```

Why is this and how can I make it return `None`? Note: setting `fill_value = None` did not help.

Comment: In the 2nd case `b.min()` returns `masked`, the `ma.MaskedConstant` array.

Answer (score 0):

The code for `argmin` is:

```
def argmin(self, axis=None, fill_value=None, out=None):
    if fill_value is None:
        fill_value = minimum_fill_value(self)
    d = self.filled(fill_value).view(ndarray)
    return d.argmin(axis, out=out)
```

It fills it with the appropriate fill value (for int dtype that's the largest integer), and then does a regular array `argmin`.  If all values are masked, then all are this max, and the first one is the `argmin`.

`b.min()` returns a special `ma` value `ma.MaskedConstant`.  So you may have to wrap your `argmin` call with some sort of test for this value.  I don't off hand see a `np.ma.is...` function that would test this.  But there may be something in the docs.

Comment: 1. What ist `minimum_fill_value`? 2. Is there a rational behind not filling `None`? 3. Do you have a better workaround than `None if all(b.mask) else np.ma.argmin(b)`?

Comment: You can't put `None` in a int (or float) dtype array.